# Regex with multiple matches: pattern should delimit old and start new match

Tags: c#, regex

I have a piece of HTML code that looks similar to this:

```
<p>Header</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some more text</p>
<p>Header</p>
<p>only one paragraph</p>
<p>Header</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some more text</p>
```

The number of paragraphs under each heading is unknown. I would now like to create a regex patter to extract all (!) occurances of the headline together with the following paragraphs. I have tried this: `(<p>Header</\p>.*?)<p>Header</\p>`. But that only works for every second match.

Using the `<p>Header</p>` to delimit the previous match works fine. But I'd need to have the same piece of text already in the next match. However, it is not "recycled". Once this piece of text has been used to delimit the old match, it will not be used again to start the new match.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to use REGEX then try this one using `Multiline Regex` matching option in your C#.

```
(<p>Header</p>[\s\S]*?)(?=<p>Header</p>|\Z)
```

This is checking using lookahead`(?=...)` whether the match is followed by a tag `<p>Header</p>` or at the end of input `\Z`.

Answer (score 2):

[Don't use regular expressions for parsing HTM](http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/)L. Use some HTML parser, like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (available from NuGet). E.g. extracting all paragraphs:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html_string);
var paragraphs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p").Select(p => p.InnerText);
```

Following task is simple processing list of strings. You can create extension method to split sequence of paragraphs into chunks:

```
public static IEnumerable<List<T>> SplitBy<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> separator)
{
    List<T> batch = new List<T>();

    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (separator(iterator.Current) && batch.Any())
            {
                yield return batch;
                batch = new List<T>();
            }

            batch.Add(iterator.Current);
        }
    }

    if (batch.Any())
        yield return batch;
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = paragraphs.SplitBy(p => p == "Header");
```

For your sample HTML it returns

```
[
  [ "Header", "some text", "some more text" ],
  [ "Header", "only one paragraph" ],
  [ "Header", "some text", "some more text" ]
]
```

Comment: Same problem. I need to group the header and the following paragraphs. The problem is independent from HTML. The question remains the same, even if the `<p>` Tags are gone.

Comment: @Jan I updated solution with processing of parsed paragraphs. Useful links also added

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort. I was looking for something like Sabuj's answer though. That works perfectly for me.

Comment: @Jan if you'll check - my answer also produces expected result. Also I strongly recommend you to read first link

Answer (score 0):

If it's syntactically correct XML (meaning that it doesn't violate XML's minimal structural rules), you can simply load it into an `Xmldocument` and pull out the bits you need with [XPath expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or use an [XSLT transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14689742%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get what you want.

Why reinvent the wheel?